# Default 0000-00-00 00:00:00 DateTime values in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have changed the MyISAM tables to InnoDB. During the conversion, I changed SQL_MODE (`SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';`) because in some tables I had DateTime records with the default value of `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` and InnoDB won't allow it. I also know changing the SQL_MODE like this changes the sql_mode only during your current session.
My question is what will happen now that the default values are still `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`? The application is working fine. How is this possible if InnoDB won't allow it?

Answer (score 3):

there are two sql modes `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE` which control that behaviour, as they only apply **after** you converted your table.

that isw hy you can convert such tables but you will not be able to enter or configure such value as default for date, without changing the sql mode for an insert.

If you want to keep it remove the sql modes from my.cnf/ini and restart the server.

Comment: what is interesting is that I have `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE` in my sql modes but am still able to add `0000-00-00 00:00:00` to my table. Why is that happening?

Comment: @FarimanKashani - Was it via `INSERT`? `LOAD DATA`? or something else?  And show us the full declaration of the column.

Comment: you have more sql modes like strict that can also have a influence if the warnig /error os shown foall modes see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem of having `0000-00-00 00:00:00` already in some tables as I upgraded to 8.0.  The data was fine -- until I went to `ALTER` the table for some unrelated issue.

Instead of changing the sql_mode, I decided to use `NULL`.  The data needed converting, and that was a little tricky.

```
UPDATE t SET dt = "1971-01-01" WHERE dt <= "1971-01-01";
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY COLUMN dt DATE NULL;
UPDATE t SET dt = NULL WHERE dt <= "1971-01-01";
```

Plus checking the code to have respond correctly to `NULL` in place of `"1971-01-01"`.  (Mostly, I did not care what happened with either value.)

Comment: my hands are really tight as the code rely on `0000-00-00 00:00:00` value. I think I need to remove `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE` from sql modes. But the question is why I'm still able to store  `0000-00-00 00:00:00` ? I'm generating rows using phpmyadmin and it's letting me to store `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Comment: @FarimanKashani - Fine.  Your app has one requirement (and nbk addressed that); my app had different requirements.  It seems that neither of us can answer you 'real' question of why the value was allowed into the table.